# Swift user notification module disabled. How can I enable it?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I tried to make push notification for my app but I can't receive push notification on my device without any error. Everything seems good in my code. I need to import UserNotification but in xcode show this module disabled. See here:
[image]

How can I enable it?

Comment: Do you have an Apple Developer Program Membership?

Comment: yes I have developer membership

Comment: Add the UserNotifications and check which error xcode show

Comment: @ReinierMelian its the point xcode not show any error

Comment: Is this a Firebase question as that tag is on the question. If so, did you go through the Firebase Getting Started guide [Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging)

Comment: @makeser Have you cleaned your project, deleted derived data and restarted Xcode? Often worth mentioning.